# Are circles many-to-many mappings?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

In a circle, each $x$-value can be mapped to one $y$-value above and one $y$-value below the $x$-axis.

Each $y$-value can be mapped to the one $x$-values on the left and another on the right of the $y$-axis.

Considering the fact that the $x$-values constitute the domain and the $y$-values are the range, would a circle not be a many-to-many mapping?

Comment: You are correct. There is not an explicit function which describes entirely a given circle. We have to use say an implicit equation or a parametrisation of the curve.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: a function cannot be one-to-many, so you cannot say "many-to-many function." I think one might say "many-to-many relationship" instead, or something like that.

Comment: The mark scheme of the question I am doing states that a circle is a 'one-to-many mapping' and that it is 'not a function'. Does this mean that the mark scheme is incorrect?

Comment: I have edited the question from 'functions' to 'mappings' to make sense.

Comment: It is "one-to-many" - each (single) point in the x-axis maps to two points in the y-axis, or a pair of points

Comment: Wouldn't each point on the y-axis map to two points on the x-axis?

Comment: You can parametrize the circle as a map from the the half open interval $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: The greatest and least points on $y$ axis only map to one $x$ value (for circle $x^2+y^2=r^2.$

Comment: @coffemath Thank you, this finally makes sense!

Comment: @coffemath I'm confused again. Are circles many-to-many or not? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abB9rWbOdUw